# TFS2013.4 Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4 Template

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

We are using the Visual Studio Scrum 2013.2 process template on TFS2013.2 with no problems.
Today, we upgraded to TFS2013.4 (and Visual Studio 2013.4), with no problems during the upgrade.
One of the new features is a configurable option about [whether Bugs are shown on the backlog or not](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update4-rc-vs.aspx)

The screen should look like the last screenshot in the link above (note the new feature in the orange box at the bottom where it says Bugs under the heading Teams choose whether or not to track bugs on their backlog), but instead I see this:

> [image]
>
> *TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration. [Learn about how to correct your configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163.aspx)*

However that page says:

> *If you’re using a Scrum project, bugs already appear on your backlog.*

which is true (they always have done), but doesn't explain how to fix this error.

I thought initially this was because the team project was using a 2013.2 template which I needed to upgrade to 2013.4 (as I originally had to when I applied update 2 on top of the RTM of TFS2013) but the prompt you usually get on the left hand side to do the upgrade is not there.

To rule this out, I created a brand new team project (using the Scrum 2013.4 template from the start) but this has the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really a need to enable this feature, until Microsoft allows to choose between having bugs on the product backlog or the sprint backlog. The feature is introduced to allow MSF teams to show bugs on the backlog. For Scrum projects it essentially results in bugs being hidden from the backlog. If this is what you want (or want to control easily), this is how to do it.

For more information, also read the following two blog posts:

- [Enabling Bug on the Backlog for the Scrum Process Template](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/12/enabling-bug-on-backlog-feature-for.html)
- [Enabling Requirements Based Suites for any work item type](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/12/enabling-requirement-based-suites-for.html)

To fix the error you need to remove the Bug work item from the `Microsoft.RequirementCategory` and add it to the `Microsoft.BugCategory`:

---

### Standard solution

In the `Categories.xml`:

> `<CATEGORY name="Bug Category" refname="Microsoft.BugCategory">
>     <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
>   </CATEGORY>
>   <CATEGORY name="Requirement Category" refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory">
>     <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item" />`
>   <s>`<WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />`</s>
>   `</CATEGORY>`

And add this to the `ProcessConfiguration.xml`:

```
<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
  <States>
    <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Approved" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Committed" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Done" type="Complete" />
  </States>
</BugWorkItems>
```

There is a bug in MTM at the moment though, which will prevent you from adding a Requirement Based Suite for a Bug when you enable this.

---

### Advanced solution

The following change works around the bug in MTM:

In the `Categories.xml`:

```
<CATEGORY name="Bug Category" refname="Microsoft.BugCategory">
  <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY name="Requirement Category" refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory">
  <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item" />
  <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY name="Planning Category" refname="Custom.PlanningCategory">
  <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item" />
</CATEGORY>
```

And then configuring the Product Backlog to look at the `Custom.PlanningCategory` instead of the `Microsoft.RequirementCategory` by updating the `ProcessConfiguration.xml`:

> `<RequirementBacklog`**`category="Custom.PlanningCategory"`**
>             `parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Product Backlog" 
>             singularName="Product Backlog Item">`

And add this to `ProcessConfiguration.xml` as well:

```
<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
  <States>
    <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Approved" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Committed" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Done" type="Complete" />
  </States>
</BugWorkItems>
```

This basically allows you to show bugs on the backlog or not. **It doesn't allow you to choose whether to show the bugs on the product Backlog or the Sprint backlog.**

Comment: Thanks Jesse, however I'm not sure how to modify the Categories.xml. I've previously (on another project) modified the ProcessConfiguration.xml to add a couple of fields using powershell and '& $WitAdmin importprocessconfig' etc, but how do I do it for the Categories.xml?

Comment: `witadmin exportcategories` and then `witadmin importategories`

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I found and changed the line in the Categories.xml, however my ProcessConfiguration.xml already has the lines in you suggested (although with the key values in a different order):`<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="Proposed" value="Approved" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Committed" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>`

Comment: Ok, just changing the Categories.xml as you have described has fixed the problem (I didn't need to change ProcessConfig), thank you!

Comment: Note: To fix the 2013.2 project, I **did** have to make the second change you suggested to the ProcessConfiguration (the change was already present in the 2013.4 project). Thank you!